# Usage of こらえる　【堪える】

Tags: grammar, usage

I'm wondering which one would be the correct way to use こらえる in a sentence, and - if both are, is there perhaps any difference in meaning?

Two examples I had in mind are:

> 涙をこらえて、話していた。
>
> 涙をこらえながら、話していた。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are OK.  One example of each, both talking about death of a loved one.

- [涙をこらえて、話していた。](http://blog.goo.ne.jp/emp007062/e/88376ca544c078c4953dbc0c0e75fa1d) (a beloved rabbit)
- [涙をこらえながら、話していた。](http://news.livedoor.com/article/detail/12078868/) (a beloved brother)

Update in response to comment:

- Question 1) "which would be ... correct ...?"

  - Answer 1) They are both
    correct (as shown by examples)
- Question 2) "any difference in
  meaning?"

  - Answer 2) The closest answer is no.  But do people choose
    slightly more flowery language when they want to transmit dramatic
    emotion?  Yes.  So for an expression like "涙をこらえ～" when talking about
    death of a loved one, it is not surprising to find "ながら" often used. 
    Conversely, the of use "て" to talk about the death of the rabbit *might*
    have been intentional on the part of the nursery school teacher,
    deliberately downplaying the seriousness.  Human languages can carry imprecise fuzzy emotional information.  Therefore the interpretation must also be fuzzy.

Comment: I rather meant the nuanse that comes with using a different grammar structure. I don't really see how it would differentiate the level of affection (which I suppose you mean by giving rabbit and a brother as examples)

Comment: @czesia - I have updated my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: Somebody gave a down vote here - please be a hero and state your reason.